Is the efficiency of a balanced lever 100 percent?
I was kicking around some lever concepts, actual mechanical advantage and ideal mechanical advantage.
Oftentimes we say that ideal mechanical advantage for a class I lever is
$$IMA = \frac{d_E}{d_R}$$
where $d_E$ is the effort distance (the distance to force applied) and $d_R$ is the resistance distance (the distance along the lever to the load). We'll assume no friction or other losses and neglect the mass of the lever itself (that's why it's "ideal" right?)
So to find the efficiency of a lever we look for the actual mechanical advantage, which is
$$AMA = \frac{F_R}{F_E}$$
where $F_E$ is the effort (applied) force and the $F_R$ is the load, or resistance.
Our efficiency as a percentage is $$\frac{AMA}{IMA}(100)$$
Well and good. If, for example, I have a 7-foot long lever with the fulcrum 2 feet from the end, my ideal advantage is
$$IMA=\frac{5~\text{ft}}{2~\text{ft}}=2.5$$
If I want to balance the lever I want the moments on each side of the fulcrum to be equal. Again, ignoring the mass of the lever itself, the moments of effort ($M_E$) and resistance ($M_R$) on each side should be equal.
So we can write these as
$$M_E = F_{E}d_E \text{   and   } M_R = F_{R}d_R \text{   so   } F_{E}d_E=F_{R}d_R$$
Let's say I put 10 pounds on the short side of the lever (it's the load). So plugging the numbers in to find the weight to balance should look like this:
$$\begin{align}
F_{E}d_E &= F_{R}d_R\\
\\
F_{E}(5~\text{ft}) &= (10~\text{lbf})(2~\text{ft})\\
\\
F_{E} &= \frac{(10~\text{lbf})(2~\text{ft})}{(5~\text{ft})}\\
\\
F_E &= 4~\text{lbf}
\end{align}$$
And that means my actual mechanical advantage would be 2.5, (the ratio of forces) which means my efficiency would be 100%. That seems wrong to me, and I wanted to check the conceptual gap I was running into here. Knowing that no lever is perfect-- there are always frictional losses and the mass of the lever itself. So if I were to actually do this experiment I wouldn't get that ratio of pound-forces.
Because as I understand it efficiency then, would be measured empirically, rather than from first principles.
If the lever is NOT balanced, the situation actually makes more sense to me, as if I were to put a 10 pound weight on the short end and a five-pound weight on the long side, my actual mechanical advantage would be 2 and we would have
$\frac{AMA}{IMA}(100) = \frac{2}{2.5}(100) = 80 \% $
But then we get to situations where I put more weight than 4 lbs on the long side, and I would get efficiencies above 100 % (which means it is unbalanced?)
In any case, I feel like there is something missing conceptually here, since no lever can be more than 100% efficient(?) Because the results I am getting say that a perfectly balanced lever is 100 percent efficient, which seems wrong.

How are you accounting for fulcrum friction in your AMA?

Right, I just realized that I was getting into some circular assumptions.


And that means my actual mechanical advantage would be 2.5, (the ratio
of forces) which means my efficiency would be 100%. That seems wrong to me,
and I wanted to check the conceptual gap I was running into here.

Well since you're already assuming that the balance is ideal (no friction is accounted), it makes perfect sense for the efficiency to be $100\%$

If the lever is NOT balanced, the situation actually makes more sense to me

If the level is not balanced, the masses will be accelerated, and your formula for work efficiency simply wouldn't work because it doesn't take their change in kinetic energy into account. So your 20% loss in energy is not due to efficiency, but due to it being converted into kinetic energy. Similarly, if you push from the other side, the system converts kinetic energy into potential energy while moving the balance since its being deccelerated, otherwise it would move in the opposite direction. This results in additional work, hence the over 100% "efficiency".

Ah, yes. As I noted above you just have to do the experiment empirically (or at least assuming some $\mu$ value in the hinge or whatever, as well as figuring in the mass and weight of the lever)

The values of $F_R$ and $F_E$ you plugged in for the AMA are the same values that determine the IMA for the given lever arms, so you have proved nothing.
The AMA must account for friction. When there is friction in the fulcrum (at the pivot) the fulcrum presents an additional (to the load) moment that is absent for an ideal fulcrum. The makes the actual required effort $F_E$ greater than the ideal $F_E$ in order to overcome that additional moment resistance. That value of $F_E$ is determined by test.
Hope this helps.

Yes, I realized that (d'OH!) the AMA by definition is really determined empirically; you have to come up with values for stuff like friction and go from there.
